# I am trying to write a function to sum the alternate odds less than 1000 and return the value

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def sumodds(n):
    for number in range(1,1000,4):
        add = sum(number)
        print(add)
sumodds(1000)
```

I keep getting the error `'int' object is not iterable`.

Comment: at each iteration, `number` is assigned to the next value in the iterable created by `range(1, 1000, 4)`. so `number` is an integer, but the `sum` function takes a list or other iterable, not a single integer.

Answer (score 0):

The `sum` function expects to be given an iterable argument, like a list or a generator. You're passing it a single number. Try passing the `range` directly to `sum`, rather than doing a loop yourself. Or if you do need the loop so you can print out the running sum, just add the numbers yourself:

```
def sumodds(): # not sure what `n` does in your code
    total = sum(range(1, 1000, 4) # first version
    print("total from sum()", total)

    total2 = 0
    for number in range(1, 1000, 4):
        total2 += number  # second version, where we do the summing ourselves
        print(total2)     # so that we can print the partial results as we go
    print("total calculated manually", total2)
```

Answer (score 0):

The sum function expects a list (or iterator).  You are trying to do its job by calling it for each item in your range.  The sum() function processes the range on its own and returns the total.

```
result = sum(range(1,1000,4))

# 124750
```